# how to send a signature Image from Ipad to server system via http?

Tags: iphone, ipad, jakarta-ee

I want to send a form details(name , age etc ..) and the signature of the person as a Image from Ipad to an java web application server.

[http://192.168.1.100:8080/Intranet/checkforimage.htm?name=meena&image=****][1]

I want to know how should I send the image from ipad to the server via http.

Since the server side coding is in java. I am comfortable to receive as bytearray and use.

But the problem is how to convert the image in Ipad to bytearray and to send via HTTP?

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

**1) Capture the screen shot of your form after filling all the details and save it as an UIImage object. You can capture the screen shot using below function:**

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
```

CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;

}

**2) Convert UIImage object to NSData object.
3) Send NSData to server using NSURLConnection.**

Comment: Nitni .. I don want to take any screen shot . Assume I have an image in the Ipad and I need to change it in Byte array form . How shall I do .Will be great if u can give the code snippet .

Comment: Please have a look at my other answer and if you have any question regarding iPhone you can call me at 09274856462 at any time.

Answer (score 0):

OK try below code:

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

this will return PNG representation of your UIImage object in the form of NSData.

In case your image is JPEG or JPG than you can use the following:

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

You can send this "imageData" directly to server using NSURLConnection.